# Get class of surrounding div (Javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="group group2">
  <div class="groupHeader">New Group</div>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="moreLinks">Add a link</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the class "group2" when the user clicks the class "groupHeader"?
I tried it with `prev()`but it returned `undefined`.

Comment: .parent() is what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.parent()` or `.closest()` instead of `.prev()` like this:

```
$(".groupHeader").closest("div").attr("class");
$(".groupHeader").parent("div").attr("class");
```

Comment: Thanks all of you guys! `parent()` worked for me. Silly me :D

Comment: @ColdStormy Glad, that it helped you! Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `.parent()` instead of `.prev()` as the div element with class group2 is immediate parent and not previous sibling.

```
$(".groupHeader").click(function(){
 var classnames = $(this).parent().attr("class")
});
```

Answer (score 5):

use **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

```
$(".groupHeader").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().attr("class");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery **parent()** function instead:

```
$( ".groupHeader" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().css( "background", "yellow" ); 
});
```

I made a fiddle for you here ;-)
https://jsfiddle.net/qLkt5z83/

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for "group2" so here you go:

```
$(".groupHeader").click(function()
{
    var groupNo = $(this).parent().attr("class").replace('group ', '');

    alert(groupNo);
});
```